# Error "INCORRECT_PASSWORD" in postman console on sending request with Client Certificate

Tags: postman, client-certificates

I am consuming PCC API, There are two way by using different URLs:

1. https://connect.pointclickcare.com/auth/token
2. https://connect2.pointclickcare.com/auth/token

Both using same haeder and bodey excpet onre thinh that is 2nd URLs need two SSL Authentication.

I am able to consume with 1st URL.

Now I added client certificate to try to consume 2nd URL, however I am facing error and also two less value are being sent in header(Same Request
parameter is being used I only change URL [image]for both request.)

Error: INCORRECT_PASSWORD

Screenshot is attached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the problem, Passphrase was not added for  Client Certificate being sent with http request. so I added with passphrase and now it worked fine.